# Why this verilog assignment is wrong?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga

I'm trying to solve this problem from altera Lab.

[image]

Here's my code :

```
module AlteraLAB2
(
    input [17:0] SW,
    output [17:0] LEDR,
    output [7:0] LEDG
);
wire S;
wire [7:0] X,Y,M;

//Use switch SW17 on the DE2 board as the s input, switches SW7−0 as the X input and SW15−8 as the Y input
assign S = SW[17];
assign X = SW[7:0];
assign Y = SW[15:8];

//Connect the SW switches to the red lights LEDR and connect the output M to the green lights LEDG7−0
assign LEDR = SW[17:0];
assign LEDG = M;


//The multiplexer can be described by the following Verilog statement: assign m=(~s & x)|(s & y); 
assign M[0] = (~S & X[0]) | (S & Y[0]);
assign M[1] = (~S & X[1]) | (S & Y[1]);
assign M[2] = (~S & X[2]) | (S & Y[2]);
assign M[3] = (~S & X[3]) | (S & Y[3]);
assign M[4] = (~S & X[4]) | (S & Y[4]);
assign M[5] = (~S & X[5]) | (S & Y[5]);
assign M[6] = (~S & X[6]) | (S & Y[6]);
assign M[7] = (~S & X[7]) | (S & Y[7]);
endmodule
```

I solved it assigning step by step the values in M, but I don't understand why this does not work:

```
M=(~S & X) | (S & Y);
```

Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the bit widths of the signals in the expression

```
M=(~S & X) | (S & Y);
```

`S` is only one bit while `X` is 8 bits. The bitwise AND of the two will result in a one-bit result, which is not what you want.

It's common in Verilog to use a ternary expression in situations like this.  For example,

```
assign M = S ? Y : X;
```

Answer (score 3):

It does not work because S is a 1-bit signal and Y is an 8-bit signal.  When you bitwise AND a 1-bit signal with an 8-bit signal, the 1-bit signal (S) is left extended with 0's.

For example, if S=1 and Y='hff, (S & Y) = (8'b0000_0001 & 8'b1111_1111) = 8'b0000_0001.

The same goes for (~S & X).

Using the replicated concatenation operator will work:

```
assign M = (~{8{S}} & X) | ({8{S}} & Y);
```

It is more conventional in Verilog to use the ternary operator to describe a mux:

```
assign M = (S) ? Y : X;
```